# Multiple WordPress Sub directories AWS Linux/Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I am new to both word press and Linux and have been experiencing issues when attempting to setup multiple word press staging sites.

What I have currently,

4 Sub-Directories

```
/var/www/html/Sub1
/var/www/html/Sub2
/var/www/html/Sub3
/var/www/html/Sub4
```

I have configured my go Daddy domain to point to AWS nameservers. I have also associated an elastic IP to my EC2 instance and within Route 53 I have setup the following

```
myDomain.com pointing to elastic IP
subdomain1.mydomain.com pointing to elastic IP
subdomain2.mydomain.com pointing to elastic IP
subdomain3.,ydomain.com pointing to elastic IP
```

If I go to the following URL
mydomain.com/Sub1 it shows my wp blog and mydomain.com/Sub1/wp-admin works perfect same for the following

```
mydomain.com/Sub2 & mydomain.com/Sub2/wp-admin/
mydomain.com/Sub3 & mydomain.com/Sub3/wp-admin/
mydomain.com/Sub4 & mydomain.com/Sub4/wp-admin/
```

What I really want to have happen is

```
mydomain.com point to the first subdirectory site
subdomain1.mydomain.com point to the second subdirectory site
subdomain2.mydomain.com point to the third subdirectory site
subdomain3.mydomain.com point to the fourth subdirectory site
```

I have been reading through blogs, troubleshooting sites and tutorials but I cannot figure out how to achieve the above.

I tried create virtual hosts in the apache conf file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf one for each sub directory site. I could achieve the first part of the problem, where mydomain.com did point to the first subdirectory site and subdomain1.mydomain.com pointed to the second subdirectory site. However the issue was if i tried to look for mydomain.com/wp-admin I got an error as there was some sort of redirection happening for example:

mydomain.com/wp-admin tried to redirect to mydomain.com/Sub1/wp-admin

Below is what the virtual host config updates I had made :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Sub1
    <Directory /var/www/html/Sub1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I had also updated the main

section of the conf file to update AllowOverride none to All

Can someone point me in the right direction as im not sure if i have missed something here?

Thanks in advance.